# Use SQL in C# to get a Database's Drive Letter

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am trying to find out what drive a database is on, on the server. To further elaborate, there is a sever "MyServer" and three databases on that server.  Databases A and B are on the "C:\" Drive of that server and database C is on the "D:\" Drive.  I want to know how I can use the connection string to try and get the drive letter so that when a user selects a database from an application it tells them what drive that database is on.

Currently I am trying the following means and not getting the correct response:

```
Private void GetDriveLetter()
{
   string connectionString = String.Format(DatabaseInfo.CONNECTIONSTRING_TEMPLATE, dbName, server)
   try
   {
     using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
       cn.Open();
       Server srv = new Server(new ServerConnection(cn));
       Database database = new Database(srv, dbName);
       txtDriveLetter.Text = database.PrimaryFilePath;
       cn.Close();
     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
      myException = ex.Message
    }
}
```

DatabaseInfo is just a class we use for reading SQL Servers and database names, and myException is a function that writes exceptions to a log file. The issue I am having is that no matter what I do I get an exception that says PrimaryFilePath is never set. Am I doing something wrong/missing something, or is this just not the correct way to go about this?

EDIT: Sorry never posted the exception
    To accomplish this action, set property PrimaryFilePath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always run a query against your `sys` catalog views inside SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.master_files
```

This will list your database, it's `id`, its logical name, and the location of the file on disk.

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick, can't believe I missed such a simple way to do it haha.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably access the existing database, rather than constructing a new one:

```
Database database = srv.Databases[dbName];
```

(Of course, error handling required if the name doesn't exist).

Also, of course, you should be aware that a database may consist of multiple files, and those files may be on different drives.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, then you can use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

to get the files of the current database. So, your connection string should connect you to the database that you want and then the above SQL will give you lots of information that you might find useful, including the `physical_name`. From that you can extract the drive letter.